# Parse into Properties with default values using Commons Digester

Tags: java, xml-parsing, apache-commons-digester

```
<properties>
   <property name="p1">v1</property>
   <property name="p2">v2</property>
</properties>
```

I want to parse this into a `Properties` object with 
`{"p1"="v1", "p2"="v2"}`. I was able to do this much using commons digester.

```
forPattern("properties").createObject()
        .ofType(Properties.class);
forPattern("properties/property")
        .callMethod("put").withParamCount(2)
        .withParamTypes(Object.class, Object.class).then()
        .callParam().fromAttribute("name").ofIndex(0).then()
        .callParam().ofIndex(1);
```

Additionally I also wanted to pass a defaults `Properties` object that I have. ie instead of `new Properties()`, I need to do `new Properties(defaults)` to create the Properties instance. I am aware of `.usingConstructor(Properties.class).then()` but did not find a way to pass an existing `Properties` object as an argument.

I am using v3.3.2. 
Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I figured out this can be done using the `FactoryCreateRule`

```
class PropertiesFactory extends AbstractObjectCreationFactory<Properties> {

    Properties defaultProperties;

    public PropertiesFactory(Properties defaultProperties) {
        super();
        this.defaultProperties = defaultProperties;
    }

    @Override
    public Properties createObject(Attributes attributes) throws Exception {
        return new Properties(defaultProperties);
    }

}

...
...

forPattern("properties").factoryCreate()
        .usingFactory(new PropertiesFactory(defaultProperties));
forPattern("properties/property")
        .callMethod("put").withParamCount(2)
        .withParamTypes(Object.class, Object.class).then()
        .callParam().fromAttribute("name").ofIndex(0).then()
        .callParam().ofIndex(1);
```